# Suggestions on popular client/server protocols

Tags: client-server, protocols

I'm giving a presentation to some undergraduates & post graduates (as part of their computer networks course) on real world client server communication.

"real world" is the key here. So, I want pick 4-5 case studies of **popular** real world client-server communication protocols that may help them in future.

So far, I've thought of these

1. HTTP (Text based)
2. FTP (Text based)
3. [MySQL Client Server Communication (Binary protocol)](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol)

   - [Client/Server Communication in MySQL](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Articles/Client-Server-Communication-in-MySQL/)

I've picked MySQL because at some point of time every one needs to use database server & MySQL is opensource & free. Though knowledge of underlying protocol is not needed. But learning little internals helps in understanding things in better way.

How about GIT? I'm not sure if the docs for this are availble are not. What more would you suggest? It shouldn't be too application specific. I hope you got what I'm looking for. 
Along with your suggestion please mention some resources for reading. If you have any reading material that you think would be helpful to me. Please suggest them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some suggestions that aren't to hard to explain/understand

- smtp
- pop
- imap
- telnet
- xmpp/jabber